# Problems getting System.Linq.Dynamic to work.

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have included the System.Linq.Dynamic library in my project via Nuget. The following is my linq query which works fine if I use typed fields to be returned in the select. But using System.Linq.Dynamic I should be able to use a string value for the select. I've followed the examples that I found but all I get back from the select is the string itself. 
What am I missing?

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Name>();
predicate = predicate.And(d => d.ID == "100053");
var results = from n in Names
                        .AsExpandable()
                        .Where(n=> n.ID=="100053")                            
                       join d in InstitutionDemographics on n.ID equals d.ID
                       join m in MemberAdhocIds on n.ID equals m.ID                           
                       join a in NameAddresses on n.BillingAddressNumber equals a.AddressNumber
                       join mas in MemberAdhocServices on n.ID equals mas.InstitutionID
select("new(n.ID,n.Company,n.MemberStatus,n.Email,n.MemberType,n.USCongress,n.FAX,n.County,d.NumberYearsAMember,d.Population,d.FederalReserveDistrict,d.FDICCertificateNumber,d.FRSID,d.ICBADistrictCode,d.UD_Minority_Type,d.MSA,d.NumberOfBranches,d.PubliclyTraded,d.SRAMemberships,d.Assets,d.RSU,d.FutureDues,d.InstitutionType,d.AgLoanPercentageTotal,m.CCRP,a.City,a.State,a.Address1,a.ZIP)");
                results.Dump();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake. I didn't realize how the extension worked. I was expecting the extension to work in query syntax when in reality it would only work in method syntax.

i.e.
.Select("new (ID,Name)");

(this works)

-vs-

select(new(ID,Name)");

(this doesn't work)

Answer (score 0):

If you're telling the select statement to select a string, it's not going to return the values for those strings.  What happens if you try without the quotes?

I'm not fluent in C#, being a VB fiend, but you could try something like:

Select New With {.Id = n.ID, .Company = n.Company, ...etc}

Does that make sense?  Apologies if I've misunderstood your question.

Comment: Normally that would be the case but as stated above I am using the System.Linq.Dynamic extension which is suppose to allow me to do the select with a string.